# how can i delete lines which have empty field using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file which contains 12 fields and I want to delete lines which have an empty field records.

my data looks like this:

```
13 24094 865949 9.5 361 384 2.1 536 1 20150625    
13 45945 865952 1.7 13 287 1.3 513 1 20150815 HF 7MRY1  
13 3741 866032 9.1 212 229 3.3 633 1 20150105 HF 8  
13 6582 866033 9.4 176 203 4.1 642 1 20150121 HF 8  
13 145 866087 11.0 404 447 2.2 449 1 20150719    
13 2051 866093 7.8 183 207 3.2 605 1 20150525
```

I need to see like this

```
13 45945 865952 1.7 13 287 1.3 513 1 20150815 HF 7MRY1  
13 3741 866032 9.1 212 229 3.3 633 1 20150105 HF 8  
13 6582 866033 9.4 176 203 4.1 642 1 20150121 HF 8
```

I have tried the following command but didn't work out

```
awk -F'\t' '$11!=""' infile
```

Comment: Are your fields tab-separated? If not, lose the `-F'\t'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NF` for *number of fields*

Input `data`:

```
13 24094 865949 9.5 361 384 2.1 536 1 20150625    
13 45945 865952 1.7 13 287 1.3 513 1 20150815 HF 7MRY1  
13 3741 866032 9.1 212 229 3.3 633 1 20150105 HF 8  
13 6582 866033 9.4 176 203 4.1 642 1 20150121 HF 8  
13 145 866087 11.0 404 447 2.2 449 1 20150719    
13 2051 866093 7.8 183 207 3.2 605 1 20150525
```

Output:

```
$ cat data | awk 'NF==12'
13 45945 865952 1.7 13 287 1.3 513 1 20150815 HF 7MRY1  
13 3741 866032 9.1 212 229 3.3 633 1 20150105 HF 8  
13 6582 866033 9.4 176 203 4.1 642 1 20150121 HF 8
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, edited. I just remember reading somewhere that it wasn't 100% portable

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'NF>10' file
```

Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn some fundamentals of the tool/language.

Comment: Ed Morton: Simple and precise answer as usual, but reading the question again OP seems to ask ignore lines with incomplete fields. Your logic will allow lines containing 11 fields and 1 empty field too? Is that right? Am i missing something? No disrespect meant

Comment: There can't be an empty field with the default FS since fields are separated by any white space and leading/trailing white space is ignored.

Comment: Ed: Sorry for the vagueness again, assuming another line `13 145 866087 11.0 404 447 2.2 449 1 20150719 11` having 11 fields, this should be excluded as per OP's requirement right? I might be wrong again.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm assuming if that could happen it'd be included in the sample input since it would be an important case to test against. So I'm assuming the data has 10 or 12 fields, never 11, since that's the only cases the OP showed in her question.

Comment: Ed: That's safe to assume yes! should be left how OP handles his/her input.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`, in either of the below ways:-

```
awk '$11!="" && $12!=""' newfile
13 45945 865952 1.7 13 287 1.3 513 1 20150815 HF 7MRY1  
13 3741 866032 9.1 212 229 3.3 633 1 20150105 HF 8  
13 6582 866033 9.4 176 203 4.1 642 1 20150121 HF 8
```

(or) using the `POSIX` compatible `length` function which returns the length of the field included,

```
awk 'length($11) && length($12)' newfile
13 45945 865952 1.7 13 287 1.3 513 1 20150815 HF 7MRY1  
13 3741 866032 9.1 212 229 3.3 633 1 20150105 HF 8  
13 6582 866033 9.4 176 203 4.1 642 1 20150121 HF 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the actual data, one way could be to not print records ending with space. If your data would resemble this (below `\s` denotes a space character):

```
1\s2\s3\s4
5\s6\s7\s
9\s\s\s
```

ie. the delimiting spaces would be there as space-holders, you could:

```
$ awk '!/ $/' foo
1 2 3 4
```

The record won't get rebuilt and excess space won't get trimmed out.